# Cannot apply [-] to AnyVal in scala

Tags: scala, playframework, jvm, implicit

I am writing some code to compare two double values and parsing one from string to double. Something like below:

```
val diffFun0  = (dims:Dims) => (dims.score ==  zippedSubs(dims.dimension_name).trim.toDoubleOption.getOrElse(0))

val diffFun  = (dims:Dims) => (dims.score -  zippedSubs(dims.dimension_name).trim.toDoubleOption.getOrElse(0)).abs > 0.01

//zippedSubs(dims.dimension_name) is double inside string "0.1" or something else


diffLen0 += ods.dimensions.count(diffFun0) //play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[Overloaded method value [-] cannot be applied to  (AnyVal)] 

diffLen += ods.dimensions.count(diffFun) //works totally fine
```

The IDE is showing zippedSubs(dims.dimension_name).trim.toDoubleOption.getOrElse(0) is of type double and things work fine when we use == operator. But not in other case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing types `Double` with `Int` what gives you `AnyVal`. Replace `getOrElse(0)` with `getOrElse(0.0)` and things should work.

```scala
"0".toDoubleOption.getOrElse(0)
// val res0: AnyVal = 0.0

"0".toDoubleOption.getOrElse(0.0)
// val res0: Double = 0.0
```

Comment: thanks it worked but why things were working in == operator case

Comment: `==` doesn't require both operands to be of the same type and it's defined for all types. In contrast method `-` doesn't exist for `AnyVal`

Comment: Tangentially, due to weak conformance, `"0".toDoubleOption.getOrElse(0)` will work if the expected type is double, but not if the type is left to be inferred: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/2PTuNloZRxqjT1dw78XsAQ